# Unable to find Apache version

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I am trying to find the version of Apache that is installed on my server. I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.5. I have two different issues that keep occurring. When I run apache2 -v I get the error command not found. No matter what I do I can't get around this error. Trying to find the directory doesn't work either, as I get a no such file or directory found error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try /usr/sbin/apache2 -v

Comment: Print the results of `apt-cache policy apache2`

Comment: When I try /usr/sbin/apache2 -v I get no such file or directory found.

Comment: I don't know how to print the results of that... ok I was able to c&p :~$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.20
  Version table:
     2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1~ubuntu14.04.2 0
        100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4.20 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: @jkuney8 `apache2 -v` returns `error command not found` as it should because apache2 is not installed. To install apache2 run `sudo apt install apache2`

Answer (score 1):

`Installed: (none)` means that there is no Apache installed on your server. You can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Comment: When I run the command to see what processes are running Apache is running.

Comment: And if that is the case, how can I see what web server I am running? Any command I try to find to figure out what web server I am running also come back with command not found

Comment: @jkuney8 please can you add information to your original question by editing it. You have given a lot of useful information in comments and this should be in the question. In particular, please show us the command you are using to see what processes are running and the part of its output that shows Apache.

Answer (score -2):

In your case the first thing, you have to make sure that apache is install or not
so

Run `which apache2` to find the location of Apache. If it gives no output, then you don't have apache2 installed.
or you can check in

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start

You can also check using this command:

```
apt list --installed |grep apache2
```

if none of them works then you have to install apache or tell us what makes you think that apache is installed in your system

Comment: `apt list |grep apache2` returns 115 results on 20.04. Did you miss `--installed` option?

Comment: no i  didn't miss anything ... that guy just  told us that he didn't find any dir for apache2 so it's kinda useless if you go for --installed  ..it's better to check  if there any apache2 file remains in the system so he can do right thing after that ...and I also give him "which apache2" ...may be apache2 isn't installed properly  by apt list command he can get other useless or troublesome files